# Serialized db Column returns only part of a text field

Tags: .net, sqlite, protobuf-net

I currently have a table with two TEXT columns. One of these columns is a serialized object using Protobuf-net and seems to be able to be inserted into the table fine (Checked the sqlite file in notepad). My problem is that when I retrieve this TEXT item, it only returns the first half of the TEXT!

How can this happen?

My code:

```
public void save(SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection, Day day)
{
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    Serializer.Serialize<Day>(stream, day);


    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (date, data) VALUES (@date, @data)";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@date", day.getSqlDate()));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@data", data));
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}

public Day retrieve(SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection)
{
  string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date desc";
  SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
  SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

  string str = "";
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    //HERE: Only first half of the serialized object
    str = reader["data"].ToString();
    using (Stream stream = GenerateStreamFromString(str))
    {
      return Serializer.Deserialize<Day>(stream);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
  writer.Write(s);
  writer.Flush();
  stream.Position = 0;
  return stream;
}
```

Edit: Thanks to @Hari Nair I've discovered that it is breaking at a certain character. This is the character 
, but I have no idea how to sanitize this string so it is SQL safe. Any ideas?

Note: I've tried replacing \n and \r\n with no luck and can't figure out what the character is.

Comment: the `text` gets truncated if it exceeds what can be shown on the screen.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it from truncating? I can't deserialize part of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the serializer is binary.  I cant tell what column type you are using, but if it is text, it is not surprising that it might cough on binary data.  If the binary data contains a `NUL` (ASCII 0) almost everything in .NET will treat that as a string termination character, thus the truncating.  I'd bet that if you peeked at the char array, you see a `0` right where it stops.

You could change the column type to one suitable for storing binary data, or encode the output data to something like a Base64 string:

You dont have a language tag, so this is VB, I'll amend it to C# if you need it:

```vb
' test string
Dim strFoo = "this is a string"
Dim strB64 As String = ""

Using ms As New MemoryStream()
    ms.Position = 0
    Serializer.Serialize(Of String)(ms, strFoo)

    ' convert binary output to character string
    strB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
End Using

' what a Base64 looks like
Console.WriteLine("Encoded data: {0}", strB64)

' simple test to check the round trip (and what you'll need
' to do when getting the data from the DB):
Dim newFoo As String = ""
Using ms As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(strB64))

    newFoo = Serializer.Deserialize(Of String)(ms)
    Console.WriteLine(newFoo)
End Using
```

Output:

> Encoded data: ChB0aGlzIGlzIGEgc3RyaW5n
>   this is a string